# Datatable in flexdashboard not showing all rows

Tags: r, dt, flexdashboard

I'm trying to make a flexdashboard with a datatable using this Rmd code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
params:
  color_target: H
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

Color
==============================
  
Color
------------------------------

  
```{r}
 diamonds %>% 
  filter(str_detect(color,  params$color_target)) %>%
  DT::datatable() 
```
````

However, as can be seen from the screenshot, only 3 or 4 rows are displayed, instead of the default 10 rows.

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]

Comment: Do you have an MRE that shows this behaviour? Do you see any patterns when it occurs?

Comment: I should have done this Friday, but: